# for loop doesn't continue; try except

Tags: python, list, for-loop, try-except

I am trying to search a list and fetch the values I need from it. For some reason it doesn't continue the `for` loop, maybe this has to do  with the `try` and `except`? I have now used several attempts, but don't see what I am doing wrong, can anyone help me out with this?

```
valueslist = ["Time:", "Name:", "Pid:", "VmPeak:", "VmSize:", "VmPin:", "VmLck:", "VmHWM:", "VmRSS:", "RssAnon:", "RssFile:", "RssShmem:", "VmData:", "VmStk:", "VmExe:", "VmLib:", "VmPTE:", "VmSwap:", "voluntary_ctxt_switches:", "nonvoluntary_ctxt_switches:"]
Time, Name, Pid, VmPeak, VmSize, VmPin, VmLck, VmHWM, VmRSS, RssAnon, RssFile, RssShmem, VmData, VmStk, VmExe, VmLib, VmPTE, VmSwap, voluntary_ctxt_switches, nonvoluntary_ctxt_switches = [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [] 
appendlist = [Time, Name, Pid, VmPeak, VmSize, VmPin, VmLck, VmHWM, VmRSS, RssAnon, RssFile, RssShmem, VmData, VmStk, VmExe, VmLib, VmPTE, VmSwap, voluntary_ctxt_switches, nonvoluntary_ctxt_switches]

for row in range(1, len(ReaderSplit)):
    ReaderSplitSplit = ReaderSplit[row].split()
    for i in range(len(valueslist)):
        factor = 1
        print("VALUESLIST:", valueslist[i])
        print("READERSPLITSPLIT:", ReaderSplitSplit)
        if i==0:
            appendlist[i].append(ReaderSplitSplit[0])  # The name in valuelist is not in ReaderSplitSplit, but always contained @ ReaderSplitSplit[0]
        if not i == 0:
            try:
                index = ReaderSplitSplit.index("{}".format(valueslist[i]))  # try because .index throws exception if valuelist[i] is not element
            except ValueError:
                pass
            if len(ReaderSplitSplit)>index+2: # if this occurs, then size is not in kb or MB so the usual "else" works
                if ReaderSplitSplit[index+2] == "kB":
                    factor = 1000
                elif ReaderSplitSplit[index+2] == "MB":
                    factor = 1000*1000
            appendlist[i].append(int(ReaderSplitSplit[index+1])*factor)
        print("APPENDLIST:", appendlist[i])
```

I expected this to print me the list of every new list of values, but it only printed till `i == 1` and only to the `print("READERSPLITSPLIT", ReaderSplitSplit)`.

No error messages.

Comment: What is the value of ReaderSplit in the beginning?

Comment: I read Basically Data from a file and then split the lines, so ReaderSplit is a list that contains a set of data in each row

Comment: Could you nevertheless provide an example input, to create a working example?

Comment: `index` will only have a meaningful value after the `try` block if no exception was raised. I would expect to see the exception-catcher last in `if not i == 0:`. (`pass` is not the same as `continue`, if that's what your'e after.)

Comment: @molbdnilo: thanks for your answer first of all! I just wonder, if index doesnt have a meaningful value after the try, because index didn't find anything, why would the loop not continue from there on? Because here it would be okay if nothing happens if there are no elements of that name in the list, but it doesnt continue at all, i am afraid i dont understand you properly.

Comment: @OlafGunter It’s not clear what you mean by “it doesn’t continue”. Please post a [mcve] and explain what you expect to happen and what does happen.

Comment: Possible ReaderSplitSplit would be like this:['835770.25', 'Name:', 'systemd', 'Pid:', '351', 'PPid:', '1', 'Groups:', 'NStgid:', '351', 'NSpid:', '351', 'VmPeak:', '49680', 'kB', 'VmSize:', '35516', 'kB', 'VmLck:', '0', 'kB', 'VmPin:', '0', 'kB', 'VmHWM:', '13732', 'kB', 'VmRSS:', '3440', 'kB', 'RssAnon:', '468', 'kB', 'RssFile:', '2412', 'kB', 'RssShmem:', '560', 'kB', 'VmData:', '536', 'kB', 'VmStk:', '132', 'kB', 'VmExe:', '308', 'kB', 'VmLib:', '3760', 'kB', 'VmPTE:', '100', 'kB', 'VmSwap:', '0', 'kB', 'voluntary_ctxt_switches:', '38069', 'nonvoluntary_ctxt_switches:', '108967']

Comment: @molbdnilo by not continuing i mean, that it does not print the resulting lists in the other iterations as i would have expected/ wished, to check if everything works correctly. I hope this information helps you, if not just feel free to ask me more, thanks a lot!

Comment: @OlafGunter You're failing both minimal - you can cut down your lists to just a couple of items -  and reproducible, and all relevant information belongs in the question, not in the comments. Also, you should post *exactly* the output you expect and what you get, not a description of it.

Comment: Thanks all for having a look, i found the answer!
I converted the lists element appendlist[i].append(int(ReaderSplitSplit[index+1])*factor) to an int because of the multiplication with factor;
Problem with that: the Name of the Process is not convertable to an Integer in general, so this was the problem, works no perfectly fine!

Comment: @molbdnilo already cut down the list to less than quarter size, but i guess you are right, was my first question and i couldnt find a way to edit it into my question, but for the next time, i will remember your advice!

Comment: @OlafGunter There's a handy "edit" link just below the question, between "share" and "close".